# NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID and I am webmaster

Tags: ssl, web-server, https

I set up my own webserver and installed some user-generated ssl certificates, however, now, when I visit the site (using https), Chrome displays the error message

NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

What can I do?

Answer (score -1):

just found https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/ followed their instructions and it worked in 11 minutes

Comment: This question does not explain the cause of the problem (likely because a self-signed certificate was used), does not detail the solution (use a publicly trusted CA) and does not explain why it helped (since the browser trusts this CA). Basically all what is does is to link to some external site.

Comment: Sorry for this, indeed I skipped the explanation, I thought it was obvious. Yes, I was using a self-signed certificate and was under the impression that CA-signed certificates cost a fortune.